# The problem with the movement of the character godot 4

Tags: godot

I am new to Godot 4 and I have a problem with movement when pressing the arrows on the keyboard, nothing happens, there are no errors, here is the code

```
extends CharacterBody2D

@export var speed = 200
@export var friction = 0.01
@export var acceleration = 0.1

func get_input():
    var input = Vector2()
    if Input.is_action_pressed('ui_right'):
        input.x += 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed('ui_left'):
        input.x -= 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed('ui_down'):
        input.y += 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed('ui_up'):
        input.y -= 1
    return input

func _physics_process(_delta):
    var direction = get_input()
    if direction.length() > 0:
        velocity = velocity.lerp(direction.normalized() * speed, acceleration)
    else:
        velocity = velocity.lerp(Vector2.ZERO, friction)
    move_and_slide()
```

also I use opengl Compatibility and not Forward+

Answer (score 0):

I copy and pasted your code in a otherwise empty scene and it works fine.

maybe you can give more information on your tree of nodes with a screenshot or similar